# bootstrap tags input not working (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsinput is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tags-input

tags are working fine and everything but when i use these lines :
$('input').tagsinput('refresh');
$('input').tagsinput('add', 'some tag');

it says :Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tagsinput is not a function

```
    <script src="/bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.min.js"></script>

/*function for renaming folder*/
        function getLinkTags(linkId) {

            // alert(linkId);
            // console.log(linkId);
            // $('#tags').val('a,v,c');

            $('#edit-link').click();

            $('input').tagsinput('refresh');
            $('input').tagsinput('add', 'some tag');

}
```

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ```<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput">```

Comment: ```<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="/bower_components/admin-lte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput-angular.min.js"></script>```

Comment: ```<script>
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $('input').tagsinput('add', 'some tag');
        
    });
</script>```

Comment: this is the minimal code that generates the problem and i have come to know that app.js file is causing the problem if i remove it tagsinput works fine.but i need that file too for other functionalities kindly guide or suggest.